# Easily filterable database table with large amounts of entries

Tags: mysql, mongodb, performance, database, nosql

I am developing a issue logger for my project and am running into an issue when analyzing the logged data. The problem being that this table grows very fast and that the filters used to search on data in the table can vary in almost every way, seeing as we're not always interested in the same fields. So indexes aren't really an option.

The table is currently on a MySQL database, with the following structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `log_issues` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id_user` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `type` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `message` mediumtext NOT NULL,
  `debug` mediumtext,
  `duration` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `date` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `date` (`date`,`title`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Now my question is, how can I run queries on this table when it has millions of entries without having to wait forever for a result? For example just filtering on the id of a user takes forever. I know I can place an index on the id_user portion, but I might want to combine it with other fields, or due to the way the query is generated by the tool that views these logs it might not utilize the indexes properly.

I think I might be better off using MongoDB or a different NoSQL database, but I don't have any experience with them. Do document based database have an easier time filtering a large dataset without indexes or will I always be stuck with this problem no matter the database?

**To summarize:**

I have a table with a large amount of data, indexes can't be used (least not if they need to be ordered) and I need to get results without waiting for over 10 seconds. What technologies can I use?

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: index ... index ... index ... still index!!! (with index it won't takes forever to filter on the id of an user)

Comment: As I said, I am aware of this, but queries won't always be as simple as just filtering on the id of the user. I need something better, if it exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you should decide whether you want to remain in RDBMSes land or not. Nowadays it doesn't make much sense for most scenarios, especially ones with complex data structure or a requirement to scale a lot.

You may want to check RavenDB. You can get a prototype working with it in hours, including the initial learning of concepts there.

Indexes are required anywhere, definitely in any NoSQL too. The real question is how easy it is to create and maintain them. With RavenDB you get hands-free indexing; indexes are created automatically as you go, based on the type of queries you make. It is recommended to pre-define them to reduce staleness, but yet they are the same indexes also when they're created automatically.

I see in another answer you tackled the issue with Mongo; well, with Raven you don't HAVE to define indexes yet they will be created for you.

Comment: Thanks! That looks very interesting, unfortunately RavenDB appears to be Windows only, which is a deal breaker for me. I'm already preventing relational queries everywhere in the project as I'm aware of the scaling issues it brings. Initial tests with MongoDB look very promising, it gives me results in ms where MySQL does in seconds. Shame it doesn't have automatic indexing, that does sound like a very interesting feature.

Comment: Yes but it's a community provided patch, I'm a bit hesitant of adopting a technology on a platform that's not supported by the developers. Shame though, it looks very interesting. Will definitely keep my eye on it.

Answer (score 1):

First, what is "forever"?  How long are we talking here?

Second start indexing.  I know that you can search on any field, but what's wrong with 8 indexes?

If you don't have an index it's going to do a table scan to find the information, and that will be slow.

Also, if you are consistently searching on one field, you might consider doing a Clustered Index on that field.

**EDIT**

Another option, keep your log table as is.  Then create some jobs to run (hourly?) that will organize your data.  For example, we have an EventLog table.  We only ever insert into that table.  We then have EventsByDate, EventsByHour, EventsByAccountId etc as separate tables.  These are then indexed and we hit these to look at the data.

This allows you to not define indexes, and have the inserts be as fast as possible, while at the same time being able to search data at a reasonable rate.

Comment: Thanks, I will place indexes if there is no other way. I'm simply wondering if there IS another way. I have only ever really worked with MySQL, for all I know other DB's (be it SQL or NoSQL) are better at non-indexed queries. And "forever" means about 40 seconds atm, which will increase as the table gets more entries.

Comment: NoSql (and MSSQL) isn't going to be more performant without indexes.  Mongo, for example, would be quicker if you knew the object id (not your int id above) but only in that case (and that's because it's indexed by default I believe.)  Without indexes it has to search through every record.  Is there a reason you want to avoid indexes?

Comment: I added another alternative to my answer.  Create new tables grouped and indexed by relevant data.

Comment: Interesting, seems to match more or less what marr75 suggested. Again though, it's not exactly ideal. It's a compromise I will definitely consider though. Thank you.

Comment: Yeah, it's similar... the point being 1 table for inserts w/o indexes, and other tables with grouping/ordering/indexing for faster lookups.  What's the reason for your aversion to indexes?

Comment: I have no aversion to indexes at all, I love indexes. It's just that this table is queried upon in so many ways, it's impossible to predict what indexes are needed. Not to mention that the occasional "LIKE" clause won't have much use for an index. Keep in mind this table is used for debugging, "best practices" don't really apply..

Answer (score 1):

You might consider [partitioning](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/performance-partitioning.html) your table. Some kind of date based partition makes sense in many cases. Otherwise you could partition by type if you're never going to query over multiple types or if you can manage the types separately. The key with partitioning is to never span the partitions in a query. Tables that go on "forever" really need to be partitioned or cleaned up at some point. Very few applications can scale indefinitely.

Comment: Thanks, that looks very interesting, although not ideal. I know no tables will scale indefinitely, but I should be able to store a months worth of data without any issues.

Comment: I'd have to agree, there will be some time period for which you find the event log interesting, you just have to pick carefully what that will be because I can speak from experience that the larger and more highly available your app gets, the harder it is to change the partitions. Good luck and let me know if you need any more info or advice on partitioning.

Comment: Thinking further on this topic, you might want to partition on date and issue type. If this is still not ideal I might not fully understand your problem and explaining what aspect of automatic horizontal partitioning in MySQL might aid me in prescribing another method.